# Arabic style writing implementation in textfield of IPhone/IPad

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am doing an application where I am trying to implement the arabic style of writing in textfield and textview here i have used a line:

```
[self.textfiled setBaseWritingDirection:UITextWritingDirectionRightToLeft];
```

but I am getting an warning: "method not found".

Please suggesst me some solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried entering Arabic text in the text field after setting the keyboard language to Arabic? I recall that it automatically sets the direction from right to left by detecting the character entered. You would not be required to call this method.

Comment: I havent tried that . As i want to implement both english and arabic style because this application will be as per the user choice language.

Comment: There won't be anything specific that you would be required to do for that. The text field will behave according to the language set.

Comment: Thanks akshay i will try that and get back you after sometimes

Comment: @Akshay, FYI, I just rejected one of your suggested edits: first person "I" is always capitalised in English.

Comment: Thanks a lot akshay it works .
Now if we want to add complete arabic style of represntation then do we need to transform the view ? Means normal way of representation to arabic way of representation

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question. And ideally you should ask a new question after accepting this.

Comment: To the bottom of the 0 that you see on the left of my answer. It will be filled once you click on it.

Comment: Yes i have done it can u please ask another question which i have asked some moment ago